# Image rotation in C with OpenCV

Tags: c, image, opencv, rotation

for the needs of a project I have to make a function that rotate an image in C with the OpenCV library. I know that this library has some function to do that but I can only use the library to load the picture and print it in a window.
I already have some code but OpenCV throw me an error and I don't understand why.
Here is the error message:
http://pastebin.com/5Y8Wc1SF

Also here is the code of my functions:
http://pastebin.com/w0AAeqyc

Can somebody help me to resolve it please?

Comment: please do not use opencv's c-api, it's being phased out for the c++ one.

Comment: I'm affraid it is a bit late to change it it wouldn't have time to code everything again in another library.

Comment: dear, that happened alerady 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trig function results are assigned to the wrong type

```
int cosd = cos(angle);
int sind = sin(angle);
```

They need to be

```
double cosd = cos(angle);
double sind = sin(angle);
```

or `float`. But when that is corrected, you can be getting negative image dimensions from these statements:

```
int new_width = (int)((img->width) * cosd + (img->height) * sind);
int new_height = (int)((img->height) * cosd + (img->width) * sind);
```

But seeing as it is unclear what axis is being rotated, I can't offer a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot I no longer have an error!But now I got a little problem which is that the image I got in result is mainly black with a small part (in the low left corner) which seems to be a part of my rotated image.